# How do I share html5 canvas data on the click of a Facebook share button?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, canvas

### Sharing html5 canvas data to Facebook

I would really appreciate some help on how to share html5 canvas data to the facebook by clicking a share button. I am really quite confused about this, and I can't post the code in this post, so I will provide links to the source files on git. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[HTML Code](https://github.com/safsom/memermeme/blob/master/index.html)

 [Javascript  Code](https://github.com/safsom/memermeme/blob/master/javascripts/main.js)

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer: you can't do it directly. You need some server side work. Simple steps are: generate file from canvas -> upload on your server (with ajax call) -> share url to image on your server.